# Create a single website with 3 theme options in wordpress

Tags: plugins, multisite, themes

I am newbie to wordpress and was wondering if there is any way or a plugin to give an option to the website owner for changing the themes without having to change the appearance from customizer.

I've tried changing the themes from "Appearance" option but it would disturb the styles and elements of current theme and wouldn't apply perfectly.

I want to make sure that when the website owner changes the theme(among the installed themes) from Appearance option, the new theme should apply without missing without distorting the website. Excuse me, if I'm not able to express it in a right way as I am not used to the  WP  terminologies

Let me give an example to explain you what am trying to achieve, say I have a theme1 and theme2 installed and setup in my wordpress and I need a theme switcher that would allow the website owner to switch whatever theme he desires. When I setup theme1 and try to change it to theme2(which has slider, feature section available), it wouldn't get all the elements(like slider, feature section) in theme2.

Comment: Generally, that's not possible because each theme has it's own widgets, modules and slider. It can only work if multiple themes are using same plugins, widgets and framework.

Comment: Oh! that's sad. Thank you anyways @Atlas_Gondal! 
@downvoter, appreciate your inability to understand the question. FYI, there's a comment section to let the asker know what's wrong with the question. You could use that going forward, because downvoting doesn't help the beginners in anyways. All the best!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to WordPress!

I think I understand what you are trying to do. I haven't seen a plugin that will do this. Ideally, this is what WordPress does natively.

If you carefully pick the two themes that you want your user to be able to use, and then set up each one through the customizer, making sure to save your changes, then it should work.

The settings will be saved in the database.

If you choose your themes carefully, the website owner can switch between the themes without breaking anything.

When I set up a new site for a customer, I generally set up a few themes and then show them how to switch. Sadly, some widgets will be in the wrong location, occasionally the menu locations will need to be reset. But if you've got the main parts set up and the themes are compatible, you should be able to accomplish this.

Comment: You've got my question right:) Thanks so much @Deleyna. That's what I am trying to do now choosing similar themes ;)

Comment: Have fun! Always a challenge setting these up so a client has control...within reason!